# Exclude everything in the build except one folder Serverless Patterns

Tags: javascript, yaml, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am working on a serverless project. what I want to achieve or want to know if it is possible or not is that when I run `sls package` i want the serverless to exclude every file/folder in the root directory except for one folder.

I have tried multiple ways to do it using patterns in serverless file but nothing worked.

```
package: #This didn't not work
  patterns:
    - '!./**'
    - './dist/**'


package: # This didn't work
  patterns:
    - '!.*/**'
    - './dist/**'
```

Am I missing something? Because I was able to exclude particular folders if I define them explicitly. But I was unable to exclude the entire root directory using wild card characters.

```
package: # This works and excludes constant folder
  patterns:
    - '!./constants/**'
```

I know I can achieve it by making a script. But I want to know if it can be done via the serverless framework by simply defining the patterns.

Comment: Let's try this value `- "!**/*"`

Comment: Nope that aint work either

Comment: When this is not a common question for a common situation (ie. everything is packaged by default) then we / I must be doing something wrong!  Let me explore that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and this is how it worked for me:

```
package:
  patterns:
    - "!./**"
    - "dist/**"
```

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - '*'
  include:
    - 'dist/**'
```

I'm still curious (as per my comment) about why this doesn't seem to be a common thing to do.  And will investigate that and packaging in general.

Comment: using `.include` and `.exclude` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release in favour of `.patterns`

Comment: @ChrisHarrison What is the `.patterns` equivalent of the above then?

Comment: Patterns is the new pattern =)

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging#patterns